# Why is it not working when I try to visualize a vtkPolydata python?

Tags: python, vtk

I have a set of points and faces that I save in different polydatas to later make a vtk.vtkAppendPolyData.
The problem is that python stops running without giving me any error, that is, when you have to view the polydata in the viewport the program stops running without giving me any information on why. Does anyone know what happens?

I put the two functions that create the polydata.

```
def malla(pto,pto2,angulo1,angulo2): 
   mesh_info = MeshInfo()
   #primer punto
   puntos=calculo_puntos_malla(pto,angulo1)
   #segundo punto
   puntos.extend(calculo_puntos_malla(pto2,angulo2))

   polydata=vtk.vtkPolyData()
   points=vtk.vtkPoints()
   faces=vtk.vtkCellArray()
   caras=faces_malla()

   for i in range(len(puntos)):
      points.InsertPoint(i,puntos[i])
   for i in range(len(caras)):
      faces.InsertNextCell(5)
      for j in range(3):
        faces.InsertCellPoint(caras [i][j])
   polydata.SetPoints(points)
   polydata.SetPolys(faces)  
   return (polydata)


def append_mesh(mesh,mesh2,mesh3,mesh4,mesh5):
   join_mesh=vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()
   join_mesh.AddInputData(mesh)
   join_mesh.AddInputData(mesh2)
   join_mesh.AddInputData(mesh3)
   join_mesh.AddInputData(mesh4)
   join_mesh.AddInputData(mesh5)
   join_mesh.Update()
   #cleanFilter=vtk.vtkCleanPolydata()
   return (join_mesh)
```

Answer (score 0):

`faces.InsertNextCell(5)` means there are 5 points in one cell, but you use `faces.InsertCellPoint` three times for every cell. I think it’s weird.

Comment: insertNextCell(5) means i'm doing a mesh based on a vtk_triangle